# Using the canvas element to crop an image

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, crop

I am having difficulties getting the crop to work with a canvas element. The code I am using is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Canvas Image</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- comments -->



<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="600"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext ('2d');
var canvasImage = new Image();

function drawCanvasImage(){
canvas.drawImage(canvasImage, 50, 25, 300, 350);
};

canvasImage.addEventListener('load',drawCanvasImage,false);

canvasImage.src = "Images/Batman.jpg";
</script>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext ('2d');
var canvasImage = new Image();

function cropImage(){
canvas.drawImage(canvasImage, 50, 25, 100, 100, 500, 100, 100, 100);
};

canvasImage.addEventListener('load',drawCanvasImage,false);

canvasImage.src = "Images/Batman.jpg";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My original image is an image that I've uploaded to my server, and it is displayed correctly, however my cropped image will not show at all.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I misread my textbook, and in my original code I had:

```
function cropImage(){
canvas.drawImage(canvasImage, 50, 25, 100, 100, 500, 100, 100, 100);
};
```

After changing my code to:

```
function drawCanvasImage(){
canvas.drawImage(canvasImage, etc.)
```

the image displayed correctly. Now to just mess around with the coding to get it to what I need it to be.